# Why are not all library functions not system calls?

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

So, from my basic OS class, I understood that kernel is the one who interacts with the hardware. So, if we want to interact with hardware, we need to call system calls. open() is a system call, while strlen() is not a system call. But any instruction or command has to interact with hardware, at least to increase program counter or modify the contents of memory. So, shouldn't all functions make a system call at some point ?

Comment: "Only the kernel interacts with hardware" is an oversimplification, and the simplification is not valid for access to CPU registers and RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest reading early papers on UNIX, the how and the why.  Ken Thompson was a strong advocate for the kernel consisting only of the things that could not be implemented outside of the kernel.

At that time; outside of the kernel corresponded to outside of the privileged mode of the computer.  This is a less interesting concept in modern systems; yet continues to drive architecture and design.

In short; open() is exported by the kernel because it has to be - it access data structures that are private to the kernel, thus is an interface;  strlen is not exported by the kernel because it doesn't have to be, it neither requires privilege nor access to other data structures.

Doesn't have to be is a trump card; because nobody wants needless functionality in the kernel.

Comment: The kernel assuredly does have `strlen`, but no user program wants to use the kernel's copy, because it's expensive to do a syscall.

Answer (score 0):

> kernel is the one who interacts with the hardware.

That is a very inaccurate statement.

Even the following program, which may run on some microcontroller with no OS (and no optimizing compiler...), interacts with the hardware:

```
int array[8192];
void entry_point(void) {
    array[100] = 5+3;
}
```

That hardware in question being "CPU", "memory bus", and "memory".

While system calls are primarily used to access certain hardware (disk, network etc.), system calls are not defined as "calls to access hardware", but rather as just "calls to kernel APIs".

A kernel can export whatever API it wants, including `strlen()`, but for an OS designer, such as the aforementioned Ken Thompson, the APIs that the kernel *should* export are ones that facilitate the existence of multiple programs, processes, and/or users.

The main concern here is access to resources such as disk, network, timers, memory, etc., but also include e.g.:

- Scheduling / process management APIs (e.g. the `fork()`, `exit()`, `nice()`, and `sched_yield()` calls)
- Multiprocess management (e.g. `sigaction()`, `kill()`, `wait()`, `futex()` and `semop()`)
- Performance & debugging (e.g. `ptrace()`, `prlimit()` and `getrusage()`)
- Security (e.g. `chmod()`, `chown()`, `setuid()`, `seccomp()`, and `chroot()`)
- Administration (e.g. `init_module()`, `sethostname()`, `shutdown()`)

Comment: _That is a very inaccurate statement._ Yes man, tutorials are rehearsing that statement without thinking about it, and that is misleading for a beginner